# Facebook SDK returned an error: Stream returned an empty response in facebook SDK5 php

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

A few days ago I manually installed facebook SDK 5.0 and the login module so users can login with facebook. It worked great until yesterday. When I try login the page loads for 1 minute and then an empty page apears with the error:

> Facebook SDK returned an error: Stream returned an empty response

the url looks like this:
[http://example.com/calls/login/loginFb.php?code=AQCCasdfSAD35L-3iABFbT5zntYQ4jJHVcko9ekG-6k-jn5aERodXoasdf7jHWEgSxxqze_K-nyAYSmcASDFaskde6wPasdfD8WHBEFUEO5gNpgLU0RJqnvVGCdYKNfT2Qm5U1pcWCvVE_YkJ6sQyUL0RrcONrqMbb7bpPv0KDUQjaO_XMAwvKEo2Jasdf31PCjxoHBGoogupX8VF5Gx6WaT4b7ZlsYkPhbQPTCdJaWrzwvfJ1So27Wsdt1Ub9WPUO07io3vxmX-P-rmzsxnk3qDSKCPJX9ks0eBtNwXA-83&state=74096150eesdfbe5eb16bffaa58#*=*](http://example.com/calls/login/loginFb.php?code=AQCCasdfSAD35L-3iABFbT5zntYQ4jJHVcko9ekG-6k-jn5aERodXoasdf7jHWEgSxxqze_K-nyAYSmcASDFaskde6wPasdfD8WHBEFUEO5gNpgLU0RJqnvVGCdYKNfT2Qm5U1pcWCvVE_YkJ6sQyUL0RrcONrqMbb7bpPv0KDUQjaO_XMAwvKEo2Jasdf31PCjxoHBGoogupX8VF5Gx6WaT4b7ZlsYkPhbQPTCdJaWrzwvfJ1So27Wsdt1Ub9WPUO07io3vxmX-P-rmzsxnk3qDSKCPJX9ks0eBtNwXA-83&state=74096150eesdfbe5eb16bffaa58#_=_)

There is not much useful information about this error on the internet, so I tried the following things:

- Install facebook SDK5 with composer
- Copy [the login example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login) from the facebook developers site which is different than the code I used before, but the same error
- Generate new app ID and app secret

Non of the above worked. I run php 7.0 on a debian 8 server.