# Facebook SDK returned an error: Stream returned an empty response in facebook SDK5 php CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, authentication, facebook-php-sdk

Last week i installed facebook SDK via composer on CODEIGNITER 3 ,it work fine and return name email and token until this day , When I try login the page loads for 1 minute and then an empty page apears with the error:

Empty Error 
**Facebook SDK returned an error:**

**and Return This URI**
[https://www.mywebsite.com/en/fbcallback?code=AQCCasdfSAD35L-3iABFbT5zntYQ4jJHVcko9ekG-6k-jn5aERodXoasdf7jHWEgSxxqze_K-nyAYSmcASDFaskde6wPasdfD8WHBEFUEO5gNpgLU0RJqnvVGCdYKNfT2Qm5U1pcWCvVE_YkJ6sQyUL0RrcONrqMbb7bpPv0KDUQjaO_XMAwvKEo2Jasdf31PCjxoHBGoogupX8VF5Gx6WaT4b7ZlsYkPhbQPTCdJaWrzwvfJ1So27Wsdt1Ub9WPUO07io3vxmX-P-rmzsxnk3qDSKCPJX9ks0eBtNwXA-83&state=8cbe21da648d832fcd2b34aceb8dfe62#*=*](https://www.mywebsite.com/en/fbcallback?code=AQCCasdfSAD35L-3iABFbT5zntYQ4jJHVcko9ekG-6k-jn5aERodXoasdf7jHWEgSxxqze_K-nyAYSmcASDFaskde6wPasdfD8WHBEFUEO5gNpgLU0RJqnvVGCdYKNfT2Qm5U1pcWCvVE_YkJ6sQyUL0RrcONrqMbb7bpPv0KDUQjaO_XMAwvKEo2Jasdf31PCjxoHBGoogupX8VF5Gx6WaT4b7ZlsYkPhbQPTCdJaWrzwvfJ1So27Wsdt1Ub9WPUO07io3vxmX-P-rmzsxnk3qDSKCPJX9ks0eBtNwXA-83&state=8cbe21da648d832fcd2b34aceb8dfe62#_=_)

im using 2 action in my controller for login :

```
function fblogin(){

        $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
              'app_id' => 'my app id ',
              'app_secret' => 'my app secret',
              'default_graph_version' => 'v3.2',
            ]);

       $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
       $permissions = ['email'];
    // For more permissions like user location etc you need to send your application for review
       $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://www.example.com/en/fbcallback', $permissions);
       header("location: ".$loginUrl);
    }
```

**this where it should return token info :**

```
function fbcallback(){

      $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
          'app_id' => 'myid',
              'app_secret' => 'myscretapp',
          'default_graph_version' => 'v3.2',
        ]);

        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

        try {

            $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

        }catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
          // When Graph returns an error
          echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
          exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
          // When validation fails or other local issues
          echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
          exit;
        }


        try {
          // Get the Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.
          // If you provided a 'default_access_token', the '{access-token}' is optional.
          $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name',$accessToken);
         // print_r($response);
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
          // When Graph returns an error
          echo 'ERROR: Graph ' . $e->getMessage();
          exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
          // When validation fails or other local issues
          echo 'ERROR: validation fails ' . $e->getMessage();
          exit;
        }

        // User Information Retrival begins................................................
        $me = $response->getGraphUser();

        echo "First Name: ".$me->getProperty('first_name')."<br>";
        echo "Last Name: ".$me->getProperty('last_name')."<br>";
        echo "Email: ".$me->getProperty('email')."<br>";
        echo "Facebook ID: <a href='https://www.facebook.com/".$me->getProperty('id')."' target='_blank'>".$me->getProperty('id')."</a>"."<br>";
        $profileid = $me->getProperty('id');
        echo "</br><img src='//graph.facebook.com/$profileid/picture?type=large'> ";
        echo "</br></br>Access Token : </br>".$accessToken;


    }
```

the same question was asked 2 years ago but no answers :
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543899/facebook-sdk-returned-an-error-stream-returned-an-empty-response-in-facebook-sd#new-answer)

Comment: Check if your PHP configuration allows for external requests. Either the PHP cURL library must be available, or allow_url_fopen must be true, so that file_get_contents can be used for the API requests.

Comment: My problem was on server side :

This feature allows you to specify certain IPs or IP ranges to which you will be able to open outgoing connections.

i added it to white list and work fine  !

Answer (score 0):

My problem was on server side :

**This feature allows you to specify certain IPs or IP ranges to which you will be able to open outgoing connections.**

Just go to your server and check if it block outgoing connections.... 
I added it to white list and work fine ! ... hope that can save your time .

Comment: u add your own IP address to white list or facebook ips? i dont understand sorry. i have same issue.